# Proper way to design an inventory system 

Tags: php, mysql, architecture, inventory

I am a pretty good programmer but I am not great when it comes to designing system architectures. I have a pretty simple inventory system I am making however I would like to know a good way to structure it.

I have around 20 pieces of equipment that users can [View All | Update | Delete | Add] each of them. However I have different access levels for different equipment (which needs to be dynamic, change who can view or delete what).

For example, one piece of equipment would have?

```
addPart1.php
removePart1.php
updatePart1.php
index.php (view all parts)

addPart2.php
removePart2.php
updatePart2.php
index.php (view all parts)
```

For all parts? Im confused on trying to design a good, scalable and efficient structure.

Comment: What happens if your business grows and ends up with 50,000 different parts? You'll have 50,000 addPart.php's, 50,000 removePart.php's, etc... Utterly unmaintainable.

Comment: `addPart.php?id=1` Are GET parameters broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An access control list (ACL) is a list of permissions attached to an object. An ACL specifies which users or system processes are granted access to objects, as well as what operations are allowed to be performed on given objects. In a typical ACL, each entry in the list specifies a subject and an operation (e.g. the entry (Alice, delete) on the ACL for file WXY gives Alice permission to access file WXY).

Source: WIKI

Please take a look at:

http://dev.juokaz.com/php/acl-made-easy-part-1 (tutorial on ACL)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tackle/

Answer (score 1):

You could categorize your products table, so each kind of equipment has its own "category" or "group". You can do that by assigning a "group_id" to each product (on a new column on your table). If you have 300 products, some of them will be on group 1, others on group 2, etc.

Then, on your users table (the one that contains usernames/password for each admin), you need to add an additional field called "group_permissions". On that field you have to store a list of "group ids" each user can view. You can store those permissions separated by comma.

```
$permissions = '1,2,5,9';
```

Each time a user access one of your PHP files, you get its permissions and do a simple check like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE group_id IN($permissions)
```

That will only return the products that user has permissions to edit or view. This will vary depending of your interface.